# Reading file from txt file and store it to linked list

Tags: c

This is the code I typed. i am confused on how is this not working well.

```
struct personTag {
    char name[20];
    int age;
};
struct officialTag {
    int deptID;
    char cmpName[20];
    double salary;
};
struct employeeTag {
    struct personTag personalInfo;
    struct officialTag officialInfo;
    struct employeeTag *next;
};

typedef struct employeeTag EMPLOYEETAG;
typedef EMPLOYEETAG *EMPLOYEEptr;

int main() {
    EMPLOYEEptr thisPtr = NULL;
    int choice = 0;
    char fileName[15] = "employees.txt";
    thisPtr = Read_File(fileName);
    displayEmployees(thisPtr);
    //printing menu
    //choice = menu();
    //scanning option selected
    //onOptionSelected(choice, fileName, thisPtr);
    
    return 0;
}

EMPLOYEEptr Read_File(char fileName[]) {
   
    EMPLOYEEptr newPtr = NULL, startPtr = NULL, currentPtr = NULL, nextPtr = NULL;
    newPtr = (EMPLOYEETAG *)malloc(sizeof(EMPLOYEETAG));
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCouldn't Open File'\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFile Opened Successfully.\n\n");
    }

    while (fread(newPtr, sizeof(EMPLOYEETAG), 1, fp)) {
        if (startPtr == NULL) {
            startPtr = nextPtr = (EMPLOYEETAG *)malloc(sizeof(EMPLOYEETAG));
        } else {
            nextPtr->next = (EMPLOYEETAG *)malloc(sizeof(EMPLOYEETAG));
            nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        }
        strcpy(nextPtr->personalInfo.name, newPtr->personalInfo.name);
        nextPtr->personalInfo.age     = newPtr->personalInfo.age;
        nextPtr->officialInfo.deptID  = newPtr->officialInfo.deptID;
        strcpy(nextPtr->officialInfo.cmpName, newPtr->officialInfo.cmpName);
        nextPtr->officialInfo.salary  = newPtr->officialInfo.salary;
        nextPtr->next = NULL;
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    return startPtr;
}

void displayEmployees(EMPLOYEETAG *root) {
    EMPLOYEEptr temp = root;
    printf("\nLinkedList: \n");
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%.2lf\n",
               temp->personalInfo.name,
               temp->personalInfo.age,
               temp->officialInfo.deptID,
               temp->officialInfo.cmpName,
               temp->officialInfo.salary);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
}
```

this is the input from employees.txt

```
Peter   30  1001    Apple   8000
Joseph  50  1002    Oracle  4000
Mary    40  1003    Samsung 6000
Lilly   40  1203    Samsung 7000
Tony    50  1005    Oracle  3000
```

the output I had during execution
[image: output]
can anyone help me fix this error? the output from my code seems to be off for some reason

Comment: You are using `fread` to read a text file. It is better to use `fgets` to read one line at a time, and extract the data from each line. `fread` is typically used with a binary file.

Comment: You are missing `#include`s and forward declarations. You are using fixed-size character arrays rather than using e.g. `strdup`. And you should use a `for` loop for a linked list: `for (EMPLOYEEptr temp = root; temp; temp = temp->next) {`

Answer (score 0):

The input file is a text file, not a dump of the memory structures. You should use `fscanf()` to read and convert the data from the input file instead of `fread` which is meant to read fixed (usually binary) contents.